# What are examples of complexity classes that have contradictory relativizations but they were proven to be either equal or unequal?

Tags: complexity-classes, oracles, relativization, random-oracles

In [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000005800844) Chang et al. provide a counterexample by giving an oracle $A$ such that $\mathsf{IP}^A \neq \mathsf{PSPACE}^A$.

I wanted to know if there are more examples like this.

Comment: If you just want an oracle where $\mathsf{IP} \neq \mathsf{PSPACE}$, it goes back to Fortnow-Sipser '88, who gave an oracle relative to which $\mathsf{IP}$ didn't even contain $\mathsf{coNP}$. Your question is essentially the same as asking for non-relativizing techniques that have been used to resolve complexity class (in)equalities; see, e.g., [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2045/129),
 [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/37332/129), [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/6575/129), or [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/21200/129).

Comment: Thank you! The Fortnow-Sipser article is very helpful. And you are right, the questions are similar but I wouldn't say they are equal. For example, I have not been able to find an oracle relative to which $\mathsf{MIP}$ and $\mathsf{NEXP}$ are unequal, and it is these sort of oracle results that I am interested in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathsf{MA_{EXP}} \not\subseteq \mathsf{P/poly}$ but there is an oracle relative to which this is false; both were proved in

> H. Buhrman, L. Fortnow, T. Thierauf. [Nonrelativizing separations](http://doi.org/10.1109/CCC.1998.694585). CCC '98. ([freely available author's version](http://bibbase.org/network/publication/buhrman-fortnow-thierauf-nonrelativizingseparations-1998))

Answer (score 0):

I found some other articles:

Theorem 5.1 in [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com.proxy.uba.uva.nl:2048/science/article/pii/0304397594902518) gives an oracle $A$ s.t. $\mathsf{coNP}^A \not\subseteq \mathsf{MIP}^A$.

You also have theorem 5.2 in [this article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/70d7/33a1dd5bd36c09b24c07e37e73d92834cd85.pdf), concerning $\mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{PCP}$

Apparently Hartmanis wrote an article called "solvable problems with conflicting relativizations" but I cannot find this online (help?).

There are also some counterexamples to the random oracle hypthesis, which is related:
[Kurz](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995883800230),
[Chor, Goldreich, Hastad](http://nwwwn.cs.technion.ac.il/users/wwwb/cgi-bin/tr-get.cgi/1990/CS/CS0631.pdf)
or [Chang et al](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000005800844)